# how to stop alarm android in another activity

Tags: android

Well, i found the same another Question about stopping android alarm ringtone in another activity

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711856/stop-alarm-from-ringing-in-another-activity-android)

But, i'm not found for the close answer for this question. On the other thread, someone suggest me :

> the Ringtone r value that declared in the BroadcastReceiver is not the
>   same as the one that you defined in your Activity, you have to do the
>   something that make the r variable has more scope in your application:
>
> you can defined the r variable as
>
> static Ringtone; in your broadcastreceiver and then assign value to it
>   in onReceive() method, then to call that variable from your activity
>   just declare new r variable as bellow:
>
> Ringtone r=yourpackge.Your_BroadcastReceiver_Class.r then call
>
> r.stop();

But, when i tried his method, i end up with Null Pointer Exception.. , here is my code :

```
AlarmReceiver.Java
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static Ringtone r;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //activating alarm sound
            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
            //playing sound alarm
            r.play();

          Intent i = new Intent();
          i.setClassName("com.example.tictactoe", "com.example.tictactoe.ChordActivity");
          i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

          context.startActivity(i);
    }
}

GameActivity.Java

private void showResult(String player, boolean isMatchDrawn) {
        final TextView input = new TextView(GameActivity.this);

        if (!isMatchDrawn){
            input.setText(player + " Wins !");
        }
        else
            input.setText("Match Drawn !");

        ring = AlarmReceiver.r;
        ring.stop();


        resultDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this)

        .setTitle("Game Ends").setView(input)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                }).create();
        if (!resultDialog.isShowing()) {
            resultDialog.show();
        }

    }
```

I want to stop this alarm ringing, from alarmreceiver , and stop it on gameactivity. But the app was crash, and end up with nullpointer exception.. how come?

Here is the logcat :

```
01-14 15:36:21.685: D/GestureDetector(25387): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 4 mFalseSizeCnt:0
01-14 15:36:21.685: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : Button Id : 2131296271
01-14 15:36:21.685: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : BB.getText().toString() : 
01-14 15:36:21.685: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : Setting mGameSet Value : �� x=1 y=2
01-14 15:36:21.685: V/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): ChordApiService : sendData : btn6, des : Tavas*M*l3RsCC81
01-14 15:36:21.685: V/Chord_Core_Native(25387): (L=86) / Sending data of type=[CHORD_APITEST_MESSAGE_TYPE] destination[Tavas*M*l3RsCC81] channel[com.samsung.chord.TICTACTOE.PRIVATECHANNEL] data parts[1]
01-14 15:36:21.690: D/chord_api(25387): <com.samsung.chord.TICTACTOE.PRIVATECHANNEL> sendData -CHORD_APITEST_MESSAGE_TYPE to Tavas*M*l3RsCC81
01-14 15:36:21.690: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296266
01-14 15:36:21.690: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296267
01-14 15:36:21.690: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296268
01-14 15:36:21.690: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296269
01-14 15:36:21.690: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296270
01-14 15:36:21.690: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296271
01-14 15:36:21.690: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296272
01-14 15:36:21.690: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296273
01-14 15:36:21.690: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296274
01-14 15:36:22.665: V/Chord_Core_ChordCallBack(25387): (L=85) / Received data from node=[Tavas*M*l3RsCC81] on channel=[com.samsung.chord.TICTACTOE.PRIVATECHANNEL] with type=[CHORD_APITEST_MESSAGE_TYPE]  byte[4]
01-14 15:36:22.665: D/chord_api(25387): <com.samsung.chord.TICTACTOE.PRIVATECHANNEL> ****onDataReceived(Tavas*M*l3RsCC81, CHORD_APITEST_MESSAGE_TYPE)
01-14 15:36:22.665: V/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): ChordApiService : onDataReceived()
01-14 15:36:22.665: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): ChordUtility : node: Tavas*M*l3RsCC81 channel:com.samsung.chord.TICTACTOE.PRIVATECHANNEL message:btn1
01-14 15:36:22.670: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : MSG Received : btn1
01-14 15:36:22.670: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296266
01-14 15:36:22.670: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : Button Id Received : 2131296266
01-14 15:36:22.670: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : mGameSet Value : X i=0 j=0
01-14 15:36:22.670: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : mGameSet Value : X i=0 j=1
01-14 15:36:22.670: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : mGameSet Value : O i=0 j=2
01-14 15:36:22.670: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : EnableNonPressedButtons Button Id  : btn4
01-14 15:36:22.670: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296269
01-14 15:36:22.670: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : EnableNonPressedButtons Button Id  : btn5
01-14 15:36:22.675: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296270
01-14 15:36:22.675: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : mGameSet Value : O i=1 j=2
01-14 15:36:22.675: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : EnableNonPressedButtons Button Id  : btn7
01-14 15:36:22.675: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296272
01-14 15:36:22.675: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : EnableNonPressedButtons Button Id  : btn8
01-14 15:36:22.675: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296273
01-14 15:36:22.675: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : EnableNonPressedButtons Button Id  : btn9
01-14 15:36:22.675: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296274
01-14 15:36:26.570: D/GestureDetector(25387): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 4 mFalseSizeCnt:0
01-14 15:36:26.575: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : Button Id : 2131296274
01-14 15:36:26.575: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : BB.getText().toString() : 
01-14 15:36:26.575: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity : Setting mGameSet Value : �� x=2 y=2
01-14 15:36:26.575: V/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): ChordApiService : sendData : btn9, des : Tavas*M*l3RsCC81
01-14 15:36:26.575: V/Chord_Core_Native(25387): (L=86) / Sending data of type=[CHORD_APITEST_MESSAGE_TYPE] destination[Tavas*M*l3RsCC81] channel[com.samsung.chord.TICTACTOE.PRIVATECHANNEL] data parts[1]
01-14 15:36:26.575: D/chord_api(25387): <com.samsung.chord.TICTACTOE.PRIVATECHANNEL> sendData -CHORD_APITEST_MESSAGE_TYPE to Tavas*M*l3RsCC81
01-14 15:36:26.575: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296266
01-14 15:36:26.575: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296267
01-14 15:36:26.575: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296268
01-14 15:36:26.575: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296269
01-14 15:36:26.575: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296270
01-14 15:36:26.575: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296271
01-14 15:36:26.580: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296272
01-14 15:36:26.580: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296273
01-14 15:36:26.580: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25387): GameActivity :  resID is 2131296274
01-14 15:36:26.580: D/AndroidRuntime(25387): Shutting down VM
01-14 15:36:26.580: W/dalvikvm(25387): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f70930)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at com.example.tictactoe.GameActivity.showResult(GameActivity.java:536)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at com.example.tictactoe.GameActivity.checkResult(GameActivity.java:512)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at com.example.tictactoe.GameActivity.access$6(GameActivity.java:467)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at com.example.tictactoe.GameActivity$TickEvents.onClick(GameActivity.java:713)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4432)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18339)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-14 15:36:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(25387):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 15:36:26.805: V/MediaPlayer(25617): message received msg=4, ext1=0, ext2=0
01-14 15:36:26.805: V/MediaPlayer(25617): Received seek complete
01-14 15:36:26.805: V/MediaPlayer(25617): All seeks complete - return to regularly scheduled program
01-14 15:36:26.805: V/MediaPlayer(25617): callback application
01-14 15:36:26.805: V/MediaPlayer(25617): back from callback
01-14 15:36:45.470: V/Chord_Core_ChordPeer(25387): (L=226) / Found new peer at 192.168.49.10 (Tavas*M*l3RsC721) PUB=50977 PULL=50978
01-14 15:36:45.470: V/Chord_Core_ChordPeer(25387): (L=274) / Connecting SUB socket to tcp://192.168.49.10:50977
01-14 15:36:45.470: V/Chord_Core_ChordPeer(25387): (L=137) / Connecting PUSH socket to tcp://192.168.49.10:50978
01-14 15:36:45.470: E/Chord_Core_ChordSend(25387): (L=394) / send to heartbeat's response to [Tavas*M*l3RsC721]
01-14 15:36:45.470: V/Chord_Core_ChordPeer(25387): (L=327) / Intersection with peer Tavas*M*l3RsC721 cached->channels=[2] and peer->channels=[2] contains 2 items
01-14 15:36:45.470: V/Chord_Core_ChordPeer(25387): (L=351) / Peer Tavas*M*l3RsC721 joined 2 channels and parted 0 channels
01-14 15:36:45.470: V/Chord_Core_ChordCallBack(25387): (L=453) / Peer Tavas*M*l3RsC721 joined channel com.samsung.chord.TICTACTOE.PRIVATECHANNEL , ipaddress : 192.168.49.10
01-14 15:36:45.470: V/Chord_Core_ChordCallBack(25387): (L=453) / Peer Tavas*M*l3RsC721 joined channel Chord , ipaddress : 192.168.49.10
01-14 15:36:45.495: V/Chord_Core_SocketHandle(25387): (L=466) / Handling internal command HB_RESP from Tavas*M*l3RsC721
01-14 15:36:45.985: I/Process(25387): Sending signal. PID: 25387 SIG: 9
01-14 15:36:46.160: D/AbsListView(25763): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
01-14 15:36:46.160: D/AbsListView(25763): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-14 15:36:46.170: D/AbsListView(25763): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-14 15:36:46.175: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordActivity : ***** onCreate *****
01-14 15:36:46.175: I/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordActivity : startService()
01-14 15:36:46.175: I/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordActivity : bindChordService()
01-14 15:36:46.220: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): SCREEN RESUEME:true
01-14 15:36:46.220: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): SCREEN NOT CHANGED
01-14 15:36:46.220: D/AbsListView(25763): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
01-14 15:36:46.220: D/AbsListView(25763): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-14 15:36:46.225: D/AbsListView(25763): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
01-14 15:36:46.225: D/AbsListView(25763): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-14 15:36:46.225: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordApiService : onCreate()
01-14 15:36:46.225: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordApiService : onBind()
01-14 15:36:46.265: D/libEGL(25763): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-14 15:36:46.265: D/libEGL(25763): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-14 15:36:46.270: D/libEGL(25763): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-14 15:36:46.270: E/(25763): Device driver API match
01-14 15:36:46.270: E/(25763): Device driver API version: 17
01-14 15:36:46.270: E/(25763): User space API version: 17 
01-14 15:36:46.270: E/(25763): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p1-01rel1 BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul  2 15:06:24 KST 2013 
01-14 15:36:46.280: D/OpenGLRenderer(25763): Enabling debug mode 0
01-14 15:36:46.320: D/AbsListView(25763): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-14 15:36:46.330: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordUtility : onServiceConnected()
01-14 15:36:46.330: D/chord_api(25763): SchordManager : SchordManager
01-14 15:36:46.330: D/dalvikvm(25763): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.tictactoe-2/libchord-v1.5.so 0x41555f40
01-14 15:36:46.335: D/dalvikvm(25763): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.tictactoe-2/libchord-v1.5.so 0x41555f40
01-14 15:36:46.335: D/dalvikvm(25763): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.tictactoe-2/libchord-v1.5.so 0x41555f40, skipping init
01-14 15:36:46.340: D/ConnectivityUtils(25763): ConnectivityUtils : It is not supported2
01-14 15:36:46.340: D/ConnectivityUtils(25763): ConnectivityUtils : E(false) O(true) S(false)
01-14 15:36:46.340: D/chord_api(25763): ***********************************************
01-14 15:36:46.340: D/chord_api(25763): * Hi Samsung Chord 1.5.0_20130828_296808
01-14 15:36:46.340: D/chord_api(25763): ***********************************************
01-14 15:36:46.340: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordApiService : [Initialize] Chord Initialized
01-14 15:36:46.350: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordApiService : getAvailableInterfaceTypes()com.samsung.android.sdk.chord.SchordManager@416887e0
01-14 15:36:46.355: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordActivity : Available interface : 0
01-14 15:36:46.355: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordActivity : Available interface : 1
01-14 15:36:46.355: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordUtility : ***** startChord ******
01-14 15:36:46.355: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordApiService : acqureWakeLock()
01-14 15:36:46.355: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): acqureWakeLock : new
01-14 15:36:46.355: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): acqureWakeLock : acquire
01-14 15:36:46.355: D/chord_api(25763): SchordManager : start : 0
01-14 15:36:46.355: D/Chord_Core_ChordCore(25763): (L=280) / Chord_init, version[1.5.0_20130828_296808]
01-14 15:36:46.355: E/Chord_Agent_ChordChannelManager(25763): (L=612) / SetSendFileLimit(1)
01-14 15:36:46.360: E/Chord_Agent_MeshMessaging(25763): (L=786) / mState[0] is not STATE_MESH_RUN
01-14 15:36:46.360: D/chord_api(25763): SchordManager : interface(p2p-wlan0-0)
01-14 15:36:46.360: D/chord_api(25763): SchordManager : smart discover(true)
01-14 15:36:46.360: E/Chord_Agent_MeshMessaging(25763): (L=485) / start() mState=0
01-14 15:36:46.360: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordActivity : Is ChordStarted : false
01-14 15:36:46.360: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordActivity : count : 0
01-14 15:36:46.365: D/AbsListView(25763): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 8
01-14 15:36:46.365: D/AbsListView(25763): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-14 15:36:46.365: V/Chord_Core_ChordUtil(25763): (L=954) / chord_random_port  [UNSET(0~0)] 
01-14 15:36:46.365: E/Chord_Core_ChordUtil(25763): (L=373) / setted_info name[p2p-wlan0-0], ip[*]
01-14 15:36:46.365: E/Chord_Core_ChordUtil(25763): (L=373) / setted_info name[p2p-wlan0-0], ip[*]
01-14 15:36:46.365: V/Chord_Core_ChordUtil(25763): (L=408) / Starting up using selected(name:*) interface p2p-wlan0-0, ip 192.168.49.1
01-14 15:36:46.365: A/Chord_Core_ChordCore(25763): (L=449) / retries? [2]
01-14 15:36:46.365: V/Chord_Core_ChordCore(25763): (L=490) / set Active Iface Info
01-14 15:36:46.365: V/Chord_Core_ChordUtil(25763): (L=954) / chord_random_port  [UNSET(0~0)] 
01-14 15:36:46.365: V/Chord_Core_FileTransferThread(25763): (L=706) / io-thread started on port 64917
01-14 15:36:46.365: E/Chord_Core_ChordUdp(25763): (L=87) / bind address: 192.168.49.255
01-14 15:36:46.365: V/Chord_Core_FileTransferThread(25763): (L=780) / Xfer Received command(SET_VALUE) from chord
01-14 15:36:46.365: V/Chord_Core_FileTransferThread(25763): (L=997) / *** TMP_PATH ** : /storage/emulated/0/Chord
01-14 15:36:46.370: D/chord_jni(25763): **** onCoreListeningCB : 1.5.0_20130828_296808
01-14 15:36:46.370: D/chord_jni(25763): **** onCoreListeningCB : Name[#*s97JtWTJlWEC1C]
01-14 15:36:46.370: D/chord_jni(25763): **** onCoreListeningCB : IP[192.168.49.1:60444]
01-14 15:36:46.430: D/chord_api(25763): SchordManager : ****onStarted(#*s97JtWTJlWEC1C,0)
01-14 15:36:46.430: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordApiService : onStarted chord
01-14 15:36:46.430: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordActivity : Chord Started...
01-14 15:36:46.430: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordApiService : joinChannel()com.samsung.chord.TICTACTOE.PRIVATECHANNEL
01-14 15:36:46.430: D/chord_api(25763): SchordManager : joinChannel : <com.samsung.chord.TICTACTOE.PRIVATECHANNEL>
01-14 15:36:47.510: V/Chord_Core_ChordPeer(25763): (L=226) / Found new peer at 192.168.49.10 (Tavas*M*l3RsC721) PUB=50977 PULL=50978
01-14 15:36:47.510: V/Chord_Core_ChordPeer(25763): (L=274) / Connecting SUB socket to tcp://192.168.49.10:50977
01-14 15:36:47.510: V/Chord_Core_ChordPeer(25763): (L=137) / Connecting PUSH socket to tcp://192.168.49.10:50978
01-14 15:36:47.510: E/Chord_Core_ChordSend(25763): (L=394) / send to heartbeat's response to [Tavas*M*l3RsC721]
01-14 15:36:47.510: V/Chord_Core_ChordPeer(25763): (L=327) / Intersection with peer Tavas*M*l3RsC721 cached->channels=[2] and peer->channels=[2] contains 2 items
01-14 15:36:47.510: V/Chord_Core_ChordPeer(25763): (L=351) / Peer Tavas*M*l3RsC721 joined 2 channels and parted 0 channels
01-14 15:36:47.510: V/Chord_Core_ChordCallBack(25763): (L=453) / Peer Tavas*M*l3RsC721 joined channel com.samsung.chord.TICTACTOE.PRIVATECHANNEL , ipaddress : 192.168.49.10
01-14 15:36:47.510: V/Chord_Core_ChordCallBack(25763): (L=453) / Peer Tavas*M*l3RsC721 joined channel Chord , ipaddress : 192.168.49.10
01-14 15:36:47.515: D/chord_jni(25763): **** onChordPeersCB
01-14 15:36:47.525: D/chord_api(25763): <com.samsung.chord.TICTACTOE.PRIVATECHANNEL> ****onNodeJoined(Tavas*M*l3RsC721)
01-14 15:36:47.525: V/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordApiService : onNodeJoined(), fromNode : Tavas*M*l3RsC721, fromChannel : com.samsung.chord.TICTACTOE.PRIVATECHANNEL Listener:com.example.tictactoe.ChordUtility@4162b4f0
01-14 15:36:47.525: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordApiService : Sending listener : 
01-14 15:36:47.525: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordUtility : bJoined : true
01-14 15:36:47.525: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordActivity : bJoined : true isNewPlayer:true
01-14 15:36:47.525: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordActivity : inside if bJoined : true isRestart:false
01-14 15:36:47.525: D/[Chord][TicTacToe](25763): ChordActivity : count : 0
01-14 15:36:47.550: V/Chord_Core_SocketHandle(25763): (L=466) / Handling internal command HB_RESP from Tavas*M*l3RsC721
01-14 15:36:53.600: V/MediaPlayer(25617): message received msg=4, ext1=0, ext2=0
01-14 15:36:53.600: V/MediaPlayer(25617): Received seek complete
01-14 15:36:53.600: V/MediaPlayer(25617): All seeks complete - return to regularly scheduled program
01-14 15:36:53.600: V/MediaPlayer(25617): callback application
01-14 15:36:53.600: V/MediaPlayer(25617): back from callback
```

Comment: can you post your logcat error please?

Comment: i already post my logcat above, it stuck when the game is finished and stop the ringing alarm.. Java Null Pointer