# Android: How can I use ringtone.stop in activity by click button

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarm, ringtone

I have Mybroadcastreceiver and when rintone is play stopAlarm.java page is shown If button is pressed i want to use stop ringtone. How can I use r.stop() in my stopAlarm.java

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10001" ;
    private final static String default_notification_channel_id = "default" ;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Uri notificationsound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context,notificationsound);
        r.play();
        Intent i = new Intent(context,stopAlarm.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);


    }

}
```

public class stopAlarm extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop_alarm);
    Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //////////How can I get r
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class stopAlarm extends AppCompatActivity {

Ringtone r;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop_alarm);
    Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            r.stop();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711856/stop-alarm-from-ringing-in-another-activity-android)?